# Sorting column in datagridview ####:##

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a column in a datagridview which shows as number of hours and minutes (####:##)

When you then order by this column the value 166:13 shows above 2:25 when it should be under it (the values are pulled through as strings).

I have tried the following but this also didn't work.  How would I achieve this?

```
dataGridView.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#####\\:##";
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could have a duplicated hidden column with values formatted in a sortable way (but you also have to intercept the sort event in order to sort the hidden column and not the visible one).</s>

Or, **better**: you may have a datasource bound to the datagridview. And you may sort the datasource. This way, the datagridview would automatically sort itslef the same way.

Comment: The DGV is attached to a datatable, I can hide a column but how would I handle the sorting?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Your original column is in string format, which will use string sort. If you want to sort according to a time, you should convert it to a DateTime before, and display it the way you want (with custom formatting, like you used).

Comment: The issue here is it is a MySQL database, it will only support 2 digit time, but I need number of hours so it could be 5 digits long

Comment: You'll have to convert it in memory. From your examples, it seems that your data is duration and not hours and minutes. So you won't be able to convert it to DateTime, but instead converti ti to TimeSpan or something like that.